# Start two processes in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a bot on aiohttp.
I need to start two processes, one is a webhook for the bot and the second is a checker that checks the processes every 10 seconds and terminates them.

Tell me, where did I go wrong?

```
async def on_startup(bot: Bot, base_url: str):
    await bot.set_webhook(f"{base_url}/webhook")
    #await bot.delete_chat_menu_button()
    await bot.set_chat_menu_button(
        menu_button=MenuButtonCommands(text="Cameras", command="ipcam_show", type='commands')
    )


async def run_web():
    bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
    dispatcher = Dispatcher()
    dispatcher["base_url"] = APP_BASE_URL + APP_BASE_URL_PATH
    dispatcher.startup.register(on_startup)

    dispatcher.include_router(my_router)

    app = Application()
    app["bot"] = bot

    app.router.add_get(APP_BASE_URL_PATH + "/demo", demo_handler)
    app.router.add_get(APP_BASE_URL_PATH + "/demo.html", demo_handler)

    SimpleRequestHandler(
        dispatcher=dispatcher,
        bot=bot,
    ).register(app, path=APP_BASE_URL_PATH + "/webhook")
    setup_application(app, dispatcher, bot=bot)

    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('html'))
    
    await run_app(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8081)


async def run_checker():
    while True:
        print("Run task process check")
        await check_processes()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def main():
    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(run_checker()),
        asyncio.create_task(run_web())
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Checker is declared in another file

```
async def check_processes():
   # while True:
    for camera_id, process in list(processes.items()):
        if process.poll() is not None:
            # Если процесс завершился, удаляем его из словаря
            del processes[camera_id]
            logging.info(f"Процесс для камеры {camera_id} завершен")
```

Get error

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```